# clear my script logs every 10 second

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have script with name : run.sh

This is my script code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


install() {
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get upgrade
}

if [ "$1" = "install" ]; then
  install
  else

if [ ! -f ./tg/tgcli ]; then
    echo "tg not found"
    echo "Run $0 install"
    exit 1
 fi

   #sudo service redis-server restart
   #./tg/tgcli -s ./bot/bot.lua -l 1 -E $@
   ./tg/tgcli -s ./bot/bot.lua $@
fi
```

and when run this script give me output like this every second :

```
[09:54]  2014 Hello
[09:55]  2014 Hi
[09:57]  2014 How Are you ?
and many like this (thousands in hour !)
```

and my server get slow in 5 hour.

i check print commands in bot.lua but there are no way to remove print it.

can you add some codes to clear my script logs every 10 second ?

Thanks a lot.

**My Script Output Doesn't Save Anywhere and Just Show me in terminal**

**I want a code such as clear command on linux terminal , clear my script logs every 10 minute or 5 minute.**

**After 5 day of script running i can (sometimes can't) login my server and my server get very slow and i must wait 3 or 5 minute to login my server and this amazing after login my server my server again get fast !**

**and i forgot say i use byobu screen for run my scripts and I think screen get my server slow down.**

Comment: Can you clarify 1) where is the script output? In the terminal or in a logfile somewhere 2) why do you think the script output is slowing your server down?

Comment: I connect my server with ssh in 1 sec. but after 5 day script running my server get very slow and i connect it and wait 3 min. to load log and after 3min my server get fast !

Comment: I use byobu screen for run my scripts. i don't think byobu get my server slow and im sure my logs get my server slow down

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that something as simple as this would cause your server to slow down, but you can add a check to your script to calculate the size or line count of your log file every time it runs.

This function assumes you are redirecting your output to a log file. Set the variables to whatever makes the most sense.

```
log_check() {
    line_count=$(wc -l $log_file | awk '{print $1}')
    size_check=$(du -ax $log_file | awk '{print $1}')
    max_file_size="1500"
    max_file_length="1000"

    if [[ $line_count >= $max_file_length || $size_check >= $max_file_size ]]; then
        echo "" > $log_file
    fi
}
```

I would also recommend using [[ ]] over [ ] since this is a bash script, as long as you don't plan in it being posix compliant and only plan on using it with bash [[]] is always better than [].

EDIT:

Since you are logging output to the terminal and not a file you can literally use the clear command in your script.

Try this out and see how the functionality works

```
for i in {1..20}; do
    echo $i
    if (( i == 10 )); then
        clear
    fi
done
```

I'm assuming your code has a loop somewhere, if not it will be a bit more complex to clear the terminal session. I'm not really sure what part of your code is actually printing anything to stdout, I'm guessing it's this piece here

```
./tg/tgcli -s ./bot/bot.lua $@
```

You could try something like this, which will background your initial process and then run clear every 60 seconds to clear the terminal window. Is there any reason you're not writing the output to a log file? That alone could solve some of your issues as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

./tg/tgcli -s ./bot/bot.lua $@ &
pid="$!"

check_pid() {
    ps -ef |grep "$pid"|grep -v 'grep' &>/dev/null
}

cnt=1
until ! check_pid; do
    if (( cnt == 6 )); then
        clear
        cnt=1
    fi
    sleep 10
    ((cnt++))
done
```

Comment: thank you but my script output don't save anywhere ! and just show for me . I want to clear terminal screen every 5 min or 10 min .